# IOS performing task in background with multiple objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, selector

I know there is a way to perform a background task with performSelector using multiple objects. I need to do `performSelectorInBackground` with multiple parameters and am not sure how to go about this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you could package several objects in a dictionary and pass the dictionary as the object. In the code that runs in the background thread you could read the objects again from the dictionary. If you only need to use 2 objects, then you could use `-performSelector:withObject:withObject:`.

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an object which has instance variables for the parameters you would like to pass?

Then just use the standard `performSelectorInBackground:withObject:` using your newly created object.